# how to get notify when image is animating over defined path

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview, cgpath

I have a image which is animating all over screen randomly using image layer addAnimation. I have added around 15 points using CGPathAddLineToPoint.

So my problem is how to get notify my touches over that animating image.

I cant use

`if((CGRectContainsPoint([myImage frame], [touch locationInView:touch.view])))`

Because anytime the frame will be last point added using CGPath.

Thanks

Comment: I found answer myself. Thanks

Comment: If you would please post your answer and accept it so the question is closed.

Comment: Agreed. When you find an answer to your own question, don't just blatantly state the fact in a comment. If you took the time to write the question, take the time to post your answer as an answer, not a comment, and mark it as accepted.